# vue v-show will not fire on data property change

Tags: methods, vuejs2, conditional-statements, hide, show

I have the following vue template

```
<button :disabled=isDisabled v-show="!isLast " type="button" id="next" class="survey-card__actions-right" v-on:click="next()">Next {{isLast}}</button>
<button v-show="isLast " class="survey-card__actions-right" type="button" v-on:click="sendSurvey()">Send</button>
```

and I have my

```
      data() {
            return {
                isLast: false
           }
        }
```

and I have a next method which check the following

```
      if(next[0].length == (cI + 2)) {
          alert() //will alert
          this.isLast = true
          console.log(this.isLast) //true
      }
```

but in template will never happen the change

Comment: i'm trying it out and it works fine

Comment: What is the value of `cI`? "`if(next[0].length == (cI + 2))`"

Comment: so the condition is ok because  I get alert and in console shows the right value but in template the change will not happening

Comment: when isLast = true the button should be removed (cause of `v-show="!isLast "`). Can you provide a jsFiddle like example? Seems like it should be worked!

Comment: @fefe here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20wz9fec/) that works fine